# BIDS report from multiple SQL servers

Tags: ssas, microsoft-dynamics, bids, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have to develop a report through Business Intelligence development Studio from different SQL Severs   of different versions(EG: 2014 & 2008). I have tried Linked servers and using SP but I am looking where I can use a single data set while developing the report with all the data from different versions of SQL. I am using visual studio 2012.

Comment: Is this an SSIS or SSRS problem?  When you say `I have tried Linked Servers` -- are you somehow not able to join your queries?

Comment: This is SSIS report. Linked servers is solution number 1 is there another way to achieve this? And I forgot to mention there is 2 to 3 AX companies in each server

Comment: SSIS is an ETL tool.  Perhaps you mean that you are extracting the data from multiple sources and outputting it someplace like excel or a csv?  In ssis, you could use separate oledb connections and use merge join to join the datasets together.  It would likely be a better performing solution to stage the data and join it in SQL, however.

Comment: sorry, it was not ssis report, it is ssas (analysis service report).Even though by using SSIS using OLEDB connection and merge the data we have to setup batch for that and data displayed is not real time.

Comment: I havent worked on SSIS much,if it is not the case as I said above,please give me the link of blog or an example to do this, it would be very helpful

Comment: in SSAS you define data source views per source system.  If you need to connect to multiple servers, you would just add multiple data source views.  These views are used for loading the cubes in the project.  You cannot used stored procs, though you could use linked servers, but there would not really be much point to adding that overhead.  There are a ton of resources out there on this, but here is a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174778.aspx  Does this help?